# How to merge(group) xpath results

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I Have following table

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>First Row | First Column</td>
        <td>First Row | Second Column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second Row | First Column</td>
        <td>Second Row | Second Column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Third Row | First Column</td>
        <td>Third Row | Second Column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Forth Row | First Column</td>
        <td>Forth Row | Second Column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fifth Row | First Column</td>
        <td>Fifth Row | Second Column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sixth Row | First Column</td>
        <td>Sixth Row | Second Column</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to use xpath expresion to receive grouped 3 records:

1. First Row | Second Column, Second Row | Second Column
2. Third Row | Second Column, Forth Row | Second Column
3. Fifth Row | Second Column, Sixth Row | Second Column

How I can achive that using only xpath 1.0?

Comment: How did you try to achieve it?

Comment: ```//tr[1 and 3]/td[2]```
This makes 6 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, *xpath* expression:

```
concat(//tr[1]/td[2], ' , ', //tr[2]/td[2], codepoints-to-string(10), //tr[3]/td[2], ' , ', //tr[4]/td[2], codepoints-to-string(10), //tr[5]/td[2], ' , ', //tr[6]/td[2])
```

The above will return the following string:

```
First Row | Second Column , Second Row | Second Column
Third Row | Second Column , Forth Row | Second Column
Fifth Row | Second Column , Sixth Row | Second Column
```